# Cannot find main class - Minecraft plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I found really good plugin for my server and It's dead, author is not updating it so I updated it but when i placed that plugin in my plugins folder it didn't work. This was in cmd **ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\BossBarMessage.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `com.thenathang.bossbarmessage.Main'
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.(PluginClassLoader.java:66) ~[spigot-1.12.jar:git-Spigot-596221b-9a1fc1e]**
This is the code:

```
package com.thenathang.bossbarmessage;

import com.thenathang.bossbarmessage.Util.StringUtil;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import me.confuser.barapi.BarAPI;
import net.gravitydevelopment.updater.Updater;
import net.gravitydevelopment.updater.Updater.UpdateResult;
import net.gravitydevelopment.updater.Updater.UpdateType;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener
{
  public static Main instance;
  public YamlConfiguration config;
  public String currentMessage = "";


  public static boolean update = false;
  public static String name = "";
```

Comment: Where's your main method?

Comment: @user7294900 if you mean public static void main(String args[]) then it wasn't in the code, I just simply added new version on minecraft_server.jar and another plugin for this to work to build path. But now I have this error when i export : **JAR creation failed.
  com/thenathang/bossbarmessage [in BossBarMessage] is not on its project's build path
  Unable to get package fragment root: BossBarMessage/com/thenathang/bossbarmessage/Main.java
    com/thenathang/bossbarmessage [in BossBarMessage] is not on its project's build path**

Answer (score 0):

Check that the plugin.yml main property points to this class(that extends JavaPlugin)

Comment: It does. "main: com.thenathang.bossbarmessage.Main"